# Install NVIDIA driver for Manjaro 18

Tags: drivers, manjaro, graphics

hardware setting: 1050 Ti

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] driver: nouveau v: kernel
           Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.4 driver: nouveau resolution: <xdpyinfo missing>
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.3
```

I have tried

- https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Configure_NVIDIA_(non-free)_settings_and_load_them_on_Startup
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-set-up-prime-with-nvidia-proprietary-driver/40225
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Installation

After following the Manjaro official document, I couldn't boot into Manjaro. Pressing any key didn't help (black screen). The 2nd tutorial gave me the same result.

With document from archlinux, nothing seems to change at all.

Can some one show me the correct way to install Nvidia driver?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I started installing optimus-manager on my laptop after a fresh install of the OS.

**How I had the issue**

I installed non-free Nvidia drivers using the `mhwd` method suggested in the first link you mentioned. Right after that, my laptop would freeze before getting into the desktop environment (I use XFCE) and I couldn't access tty.

**How I solved it**

1. chroot into the installed OS from a live CD session. I was able to achieve that using the 4th method described here https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-login-black-screen-chroot-guide/21166.
2. disable bumblebee service: `systemctl disable bumblebeed.service`
3. install optimus-manager: `pamac install optimus-manager`
4. reboot
5. Optionally, install this nice GUI tool for commanding optimus-manager from a tray icon `yay optimus-manager-qt`

**Documentation**

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/guide-install-and-configure-optimus-manager-for-hybrid-gpu-setups-intel-nvidia/92196

https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager/blob/master/README.md